# How to modify uidNumber AD attributes on Samba 4.3 from the Linux command line?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, active-directory, command-line-interface, samba4

I know I can set or modify RFC2307 attributes like uidNumber and gidNumber from the Windows side using RSAT. 
Since this is rather painfull with larger numbers of users and groups I'd really like to find a way to do it on the Linux command line. Is there a way to do this on Samba 4.3.11 (the version currently shipped with Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would use [LDAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol) as the protocol to connect to your Active Directory domain controller from Linux.
Then either use your favourite scripting language to connect directly to AD, or simply generate an  [LDIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP_Data_Interchange_Format) file with your intended changes and use the [`ldapmodify`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ldapmodify) commandline utility to do a bulk change.

```
# A simple LDIF to change a uidNumber and set a gidNumber 
# for both John and Jane Doe would look like: 

dn: cn=John Doe,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
replace: uidNumber
uidNumber: 9001
-
add:  gidNumber
gidNumber: 9001
-

dn: cn=Jane Doe,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: uidNumber
uidNumber: 9002
-
add:  gidNumber
gidNumber: 9001
-

# EOF
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked very well. Just for reference: I ended up using `ldbmodify` with Kerberos.

Answer (score 1):

Try `ldbedit -H /var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb` and `ldbedit -H /var/lib/samba/private/idmap.ldb`

Comment: `ldbedit` is definitively a nice tool, but this would mean editing by hand, right? I'll rather go for an ldif solution, it's more convenient and secure. But +1 for mentioning it.